# Encrypting and compressing

Tags: tar, openssl

Is there a better way to compress and then encrypt files other than `tar` followed by `openssl` or `gpg`?

Comment: That depends. What are your requirements? How are you quantifying "best"? What tools do you have available? Have you considered any other options already that might be useful to mention?

Comment: Haven't considered any others. It just needs to be basic encryption, where someone can't read the contents of the file, and preferably maintain a good compression ratio.

Comment: Generally the answer will be no. One of the core unix philosophies is "do one thing and do it well". `tar -z` is a slight exception because it is a very common practice.

Comment: Newer `tar` versions support xz compression (flag `-J`) whose compression ratio is usually better than the more traditional gzip (`-z`) or bzip2 (`-j`) compression.

Comment: I've noticed that `xz` is excellent. I do remember downloading the kernel and it was zipped to about 1/7 of its original size.

I guess I'll `tar cvJf out.tar.xz file1 [file2...]` and then use gpg or openssl to encrypt it.

I also notice that xz is very fast. How does it acheive better compression than bz2 and still be fast?

Comment: @user75027: In general terms, greater memory use of xz makes it faster than gzip and bzip2.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I'll choose xz and then openssl to encrypt it. GPG seems more focused on plaintext, which is not what I have

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`tar` is the usual tool to bundle files. Plain `tar` itself doesn't compress. There are separate tools such as [gzip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip), [bzip2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bzip2) and [xz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xz) (in increasing order of compression ratio on typical files) that compress one file. Many `tar` implementation, including GNU tar (the normal implementation on Linux), can automatically compress with an option (`-z` for gzip, `-j` for bzip2, `-J` for xz):

```
tar -cJf myarchive.tar.xz file1 file2 file3
```

To encrypt a file, use [gpg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Privacy_Guard). Create a key and associate it with your email address (GPG/PGP key identifiers usually contain an email address, though it is not necessary ). Encrypt your files, specifying your email as the recipient. To decrypt a file, you'll need to enter the passphrase to unlock your private key.

GPG also lets you encrypt a file with a password. This is less secure and less flexible. It's less flexible because you need to specify the password when encrypting (so for example you can't make unattended backups). It's less secure because the only security is the password, whereas key-based encryption splits the security between the password and the key.

Don't use the `openssl` command line tool. It's a showcase for the OpenSSL library, not designed for production use. Although you can do some things with it (in particular, it does have all the primitives needed for a basic certification authority), it's hard to use correctly and it doesn't have all you need to do things right. Where GPG gives you a bicycle, OpenSSL gives you some metal rods of various sizes and a couple of rubber chambers (screws and pump not included). Use GPG.

Comment: I understand tar as a bundler and the methods of compression.

gpg keys, however, are new to me. I don't exactly understand how to use it, although I do have a key. I think. I think I also have ssh keys.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/95931/463570) is what I was looking for to compress and encrypt with one command (using `tar` and `gpg` in a pipe).

Answer (score 15):

You can use 7zip:

```
7z a -p -mhe=on stuff.7z MyStuff
   ^  ^     ^      ^        ^
   |  |     |      |        `--- Files/directories to compress & encrypt.
   |  |     |      `--- Output filename
   |  |      `--- Encrypt filenames
   |  `---- Use a password
   `---- Add files to archive
```

It will prompt you for a password. Apparently it uses AES-256 for encryption and [SHA-256 of the password and a counter repeated 512K times](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45798/thread/43245ebe/) for key derivation.

Answer (score 4):

So you can use 7zip encrypting file names too:

```
7z a -p -mhe=on stuff.7z MyStuff
```